# Получить число 24 используя 4 числа от 1 до 9 и знаки +-*/()

Tags: java

На входе 4 числа от 1 до 9 (могут повторяться). Необходимо написать программу, которая определит, можно ли из данных чисел и арифметических знаков: сложение, вычитание, умножение, деление и скобки, составить число равное 24.

Comment: Наработки в студию !

Comment: можно, System.out.println("3*2*2*2");

Comment: а в самом выражении они тоже могут повторяться? (т.е. если 7 одна -  то она один раз и в выражении может присутсвовать?)

Comment: @dSH цифры могут повторяться только если на входе они повторяются

Comment: Задание простое, работает в цикле. Покажите ваши наработки, мы попробуем помочь с проблемой.